# Redux with Prompt: Available libraries or listen manually?

Tags: react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm working with React, Redux, and React-Router-Dom. Most of my existing routing scenarios can be covered using the `<Link />` and `<Prompt />` tags. One scenario however, requires that I use some "code-behind" instead of the `<Link />` tag (Using the Link within a select option has so far been unsuccessful.)

In this scenario, how do I handle listening to the prompt? I want to prevent my dispatch (onSelect) from ever firing if the user cancels at the prompt, but so far I haven't found any way to do so.

`<Link />` appears to be "auto-magically" listening to something that corresponds to the `<Prompt />`, and I'd like to know what it is so I can listen in a similar manner if no library exists to handle this exact scenario.

Additionaly, I'm using `<Redirect />`, but I can't begin to understand how to clean my state of the state.redirectArgs field once the redirect has occurred, leaving me with a different set of issues.

Usually when I can't find a scenario with the Google machine its a indication that I'm breaking some paradigm in my coding patterns, but I'm having a hard time reconciling that in this case, so any type of answer (library, pattern change, etc.) that gets me to a successful end(point) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using `<Redirect />` and `<Prompt />`. The key was to leverage the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle (it seems like `componentDidMount()` should work too, but it doesn't, at least in my scenario). This hook is called after the `render()` method, which is critical here.

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component<SomeComponentProps, never> {


    render() {
        // state
        const { redirect } = this.props;

        // dispatch
        const { onSelect } = this.props;

        if (redirect) {
            return <Redirect push to={redirect.path} />
        }

        ... other code, including onSelect which sets redirect ...
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // state
        const { redirect } = this.props;
        // dispatch
        const { cleanupRedirect } = this.props;

        if (redirect) {
            cleanupRedirect();
        }
    }
}

export interface SomeComponentState {
    redirect: { path: string }
}

export interface SomeComponentDispatch {
    cleanupRedirect: () => void
    onSelect: (key: string) => void
}

export type SomeComponentProps = SomeComponentState & SomeComponentDispatch;
```